# Is it normal for a filter to receive BeginFlush and EndFlush in a graph which is not being seeked?

Tags: directshow

I'm working on a custom multiplexing filter that doesn't support seeking - because it's not designed to and doesn't need to.

When I connect it downstream of the Main Concept / Rovi MP4 demultiplexer and Main Concept broadcast MP4/AVC decoder my filter receives calls to BeginFlush, EndFlush, NewSegment just after IBaseFilter::Pause is called but before the first sample is delivered. SetPositions is not called. I've narrowed down the BeginFlush to the mp4 demux filter.

Is this correct DirectShow behaviour? I understand the role that BeginFlush/EndFlush play in seeking but is it safe or allowable to call them at the start of streaming? I don't see much reference to BeginFlush/EndFlush in the Microsoft documentation outside the context of seeking operations. The call to BeginFlush is clearly happening during the call to IMediaControl::Run (see call stack below) rather than as a result of the host program seeking the graph by calling SetPositions (or similar).

Is it a reasonable filter workaround to discard BeginFlush/EndFlush requests that arrive before the first sample? Presumably there are many filters out there that don't support seeking and therefore don't support BeginFlush/EndFlush well.

```
 quartz.dll!CFilterGraph::Pause()  + 0x109 bytes    
 quartz.dll!CFGControl::Cue()  + 0x1b bytes    
 quartz.dll!CFGControl::CueThenRun()  + 0x12 bytes    
 quartz.dll!CFGControl::CImplMediaControl::StepRun()  + 0x59 bytes    
 quartz.dll!CFGControl::CImplMediaControl::Run()  + 0x2d bytes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps "correct" is not the right word here, is it a legal behavior? I think it is. Demultiplexer flushes before it starts streaming, why not. It could so happen it is specific to how they handle seeking, that is they flush before sending from clean point and they do it even on initial sending.

Flushing is not a part of seeking capability only. It is rather a core feature a filter should support and implement, so why would not you just flush when you receive the request? Or simply ignore when you have nothing to flush? I would say that if it creates a sort of a problem then maybe multiplexer does something else in a wrong way because flushing request is not something that looks breaking. I suppose it is even legal to get it in the middle of streaming, let us say if a source or decoder for whatever reason decides to withdraw data in transit downstream.

Comment: Flushing a file based muxer leaves it in a potentially unknown state. Should it flush all data that is ready and waiting to write to disk, should it flush all queued data that isn't ready to write to disk because it's waiting for more frames? It seems to me that the only deterministic thing it can do is not flush any date at all and just ignore the flush in any scenario. Alternatively it can just close the file

Comment: Flush methods on filters assume that caller takes care of outer synchronization in some way. And split into being/end is made so that multiple streams could be synchronized (begin all, then end all). Eventually it is a flush caller to make sure the state is stable. A typical flusher is demultiplexer itself: when seeking (an initializing streaming in your case) it makes sure the pipeline is empty everywhere downstream from it.

Comment: Then regarding writing to disk - flushing is more a discarding here rather then forcing processing to complete. Certainly, receiver of `BeginFlush` decides what to do itself, but the nature of the call is to ensure the pipeline is empty with no regard to what to do with pending data. Request to complete processing is `EndOfStream` instead.

Comment: You make a very good point that flush is about flushing the pipeline not pending data. So it makes sense for a file based muxer with no downstream filters to do whatever it likes with pending data as long as it's ready to receive more data from upstream. Of course for a file based muxer that's syncing multiple input stream the sync between input streams at the time of the flush can't be guaranteed and the streams will then be out of sync unless the muxer makes an effort to re-sync them - which is why most file muxers don't support seeking.

Comment: In my opinion, muxer or file muxer should handle flushing exactly as MSDN suggests: discarding pending data and incoming data during active flushing period, without reopening files and at all changing the queue, including restarting time stamps etc. Like, for example, in case of upstream filter sending a sample and then trying to undo the sending if possible, with further resume of streaming. Flushing should not cancel/close session, such as file recording session in particular.